# What is a limit point exactly?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Wikipedia says that a point $x$ is a limit point of a set $E$ if for every neighbourhood $O(x)$ of $x$ there is a point in the intersection $O(x)\cap E$ other than $x$. Zorich, however, says that $x$ is a limit point of $E$ if the intersection of $O(x)\cap E$ is an infinite (be it countable or uncountable) set. Are these definitions really equivalent? What I am thinking is that if we sit in a metric space, these definitions are obviously equivalent, but if we sit inside a space with no separation axioms specified, then you can have finitely many points of $E$ (excluding $x$) for every $O(x)$ and still not be able to find a neighbourhood of $x$ without any points of $E$ rather than $x$ itself.

Could anyone please clarify this for me?

Comment: You are right. Consider a  finite set with indiscrete topology.